# Monitor doesn't display anything on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, display

Monitor doesn't display on startup, but on repeatedly pressing its power button, it displays. I changed VGA cable but the problem persists. My computer runs Windows 7.

Comment: `but on repeatedly pressing its power button,it displays` can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Do you hear 'All OK' single beep after starting your PC?

Comment: Windows boots up but display shows nothing unless the power button of the monitor is pressed repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean about repeatingly pressing the power button exactially, but if you have to play with the power button in order to get the monitor on then you need to get the monitor serviced or repaired